# How can I use createContext with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I found a blog where they did it as follows:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

type ContextProps = {
    alert: any,
    showAlert: any
};

const alertContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

export default alertContext;
```

I created another file in which I set up the functions, like this:

```
const AlertState: SFC<AlertStateProps> = (props) => {

        const initialState = {
            alert: null
        }
    
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(alertReducer, initialState);
    
        // Functions
        const showAlert = (msg: any) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SHOW_ALERT,
                payload: {
                    msg
                }
            });
    
            // After 5 seconds clean error message
            setTimeout(() => {
                dispatch({
                    type: HIDE_ALERT
                })
            }, 5000);
        }

    return (  
        <alertContext.Provider
            value={{
                alert: state.alert,
                showAlert
            }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </alertContext.Provider>
    );
}
 
export default AlertState;
```

But, when I call `alertContext` in another file, like this:

```
const Login = (props) => {

const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
const { alert, showAlert } = alertContext;

console.log('context', alertContext);
...
}
```

In the `console.log` I can see that it takes the empty object and not the properties that are declared in the interface.

[image]

Someone knows what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

First, `Login` component should be a child of `AlertContext.Provider`:

```
<AlertState>
  <Login/>
</AlertState>
```

Then you need to pass the context object to `createContext`, you are passing `AlertContext` which is not defined.

```
// You should name context and React component with capital letter
const AlertContext = createContext<Partial<ContextProps>>({});

// Pass `AlertContext`
const {alert,showAlert} = useContext(AlertContext);
```